# docker-compose: Why does my webapp fail to connect to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to connect two running containers: (1) a webapp and (2) a mysql db using docker compose. I setup the belowmentioned `docker-compose.yml` but my webapp fails to open a socket to mysql. More specifically, this php @fsockopen function throws an error ( second case ). Is there something wrong with the docker-compose config?

*Note: idoit is the name of the webapp*

**php case**

```
if (@fsockopen($l_dbHost, $l_t, $t_errno, $t_errstr, 5)) {
                        $l_success = true;
                        $l_message = "CONNECTED";
                        $l_dbPort = $l_t;
                    } else {
                        $l_success = false;
                        $l_message = "ERROR (" . $t_errno . ")";
                    }
```

**The docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ****
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ****
      MYSQL_USER:  ****
      MYSQL_PASSWORD:  ****
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
  idoit:
    depends_on:
      - db
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      IDOIT_DB_HOST: db:3306
      IDOIT_DB_USER:  ****
      IDOIT_DB_PASSWORD:  ****
      IDOIT_DB_NAME:  ****
      
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

Comment: Why are you using [fsockopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) to establish a database connection, instead of using [pdo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)? Also, why are you repressing warnings in critical code? And on a terminology note: PHP is by definition not a web app (it's not running in the browser, it's running on the server), it's at best a web app's backend.

Comment: Think you need to have the same network (backend) in both containers.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans this is not actually my php code. I reversed engineering the code of the webapp trying to understand why it is failing (cause it threw no error messages) and the reason was this.

Comment: @NigelRen as I noted in the answer belw, networks was more of a typo which I removed. The default docker-compose network will do for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like `idoit` service doesn't have access to network with mysql database.

db service have

```yaml
networks:
      - backend
```

and idoit service - doesn't

Comment: I added `networks:
      - backend` to idoit too, but it does not seem to be working. I also tried to remove the networks directive from both. Its gotta be something else. Nice observation though. I removed the directive from the original post now.

Comment: probably there are issues with a way you connect to mysql. try any official api - https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php